# ask ubuntu home page last seen gone with new ui

Tags: support

I was previously able to see the last seen of any user.
Recently with the new look of AskUbuntu page, I could not find this option.

Is it removed or is there any different approach to the "last seen" of any user.

Comment: See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive Ity was removed but it was so unpopular that it may comeback one day.

Comment: Yeah this is super annoying. Mods can see it so feel free to ask until they fix it :/